# How to pass html table to laravel controller using ajax request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.3

How can I pass html array to laravel controller using ajax request?
I did like below in my view:

```
<form>
                <table class="table table-striped border-top" id="modalTable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                           <th>start-time</th>
                           <th></th>
                           <th>end-time</th>
                           <th>reserve</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="change">
                        <tr>
                            <td name="startTime[]"></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td name="endTime[]"></td>
                            <td name="reserved[]"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input type="hidden" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            </form>
```

and the ajax code is below:

```
<script>
    $(document).on('click','.btn',function(){

        var startTime = $('#startTime').text();
        //alert(startTime);
        var endTime = $('#endTime').text();
        //alert(endTime);
        var token = $('#token').val();

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        })

        $.ajax
        ({
            url:'reservePrivateChat',
            type:'post',
            data:{startTime:startTime,endTime:endTime,'_token':token},
            success:function()
            {
                alert('success');
            },
            error:function()
            {
                alert('error');
            }
        })

    });
</script>
```

and in controller I did like below :

```
public function reservePrivateChat(Request $request)
{
    $startTime = $request->startTime;
    print_r ($startTime);
    $endTime = $_POST['endTime'];
    print_r($endTime);
}
```

In controller there is no difference between `$request` and `$_POST`. Both return just one column of the table that sent by ajax but I want all values of the columns...

Comment: by array I mean : <td name='startTime[] '>

Comment: `#startTime` means "element with **id**" start time, you have no such element here. You have elements with **name** startTime[] You should be using those instead.

Comment: @apokryfos yeah your right.TNX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying to do. You have to manually construct the array based on the **correct** names of the table data. The `#startTime` selector does not exist because it's looking for an element with id `startTime` but you only have an element with **name** `startTime[]`.

You an probably create an array as follows:

```
    var startTime = [];
    $("[name='startTime[]]'").each(function () {
        startTime.push($(this).text());
    });
    var endTime = [];
    $('[name='endTime[]]'').each(function () {
        endTime.push($(this).text());
    });
    var token = $('#token').val();
    //No need for ajax setup if you're sending the token as a parameter
    $.ajax({
        url:'reservePrivateChat',
        type:'post',
        data:{ startTime:startTime,endTime:endTime,'_token':token},
```